# Save any kind of file to my database(in sql server 2008)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How can I save any kind of file for example AutoCAD file to my database?
Can I solve this with `FileStream` with SQL Server 2008? And how?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `varbinary(MAX)` type.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx